# Mime4j - Sending email through SMTP Server

Tags: jakarta-mail, mime4j

I've implemented a solution to parse Email Files (.eml) into objects using Mime4J. The process parses an email file, create an object and write a new file to disk.

I was wondering if is possible to send the MimeMessage of Mime4J through  **Transport.send(mimeMessage)** instead to create a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use the Mime4J Message.writeTo method to write the message to a ByteArrayOutputStream, then wrap the byte array with a ByteArrayInputStream and use that to construct a JavaMail MimeMessage object.

A more complex but more efficient approach would be to create a class that subclasses MimeMessage and delegates most of the methods to the corresponding methods on the Mime4J Message object.